# Oracle on aix resolution very slow

Tags: oracle

Oracle on aix,had a very bad resolution
I though i don't have resolution problem
on aix server.
Ping is fast and ok

```
 ping google.de 
PING google.de (172.217.21.131): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.21.131: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=53 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.21.131: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=56 ms
```

ping internal machine ok

```
ping ibmaix    
PING ibmaix (192.168.0.7): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.7: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=0 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.7: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0 ms
```

resolution ok

host command works fine and can resolv names
1521 is open on firewall

But oracle command are super-slow
or won't connect at all

```
yasql  / as SYSDBA 

YASQL version 1.8.4.GIT Copyright (c) 2000-2001 Ephibian, Inc, 2005 iMind.dev.
$Id: yasql,v 1.83 2005/05/09 02:07:13 qzy Exp qzy $
Please type 'help' for usage instructions
Attempting connection to local database
timeout...
```

sqlplus works but for connection it take..one minute.
What to check?

my  resolv.conf

```
search mydomain.private
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

my listener.ora(removing change nothing)

```
#
#  VIDEO Listener
#
VIDEO =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC) (KEY = VIDEO))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = ibmaix.mydomain.private) (PORT = 1521 ))
      )
    )
  )

SID_LIST_VIDEO =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = VIDEO)
      (SID_NAME = VIDEO)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /var/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1 )
    )
  )

LOG_DIRECTORY_VIDEO=/var/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/VIDEO/log
LOG_FILE_VIDEO=VIDEO.log
LOGGING_VIDEO=ON
TRACE_DIRECTORY_VIDEO=/var/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/log
TRACE_FILE_VIDEO=VIDEO.trc
TRACE_LEVEL_VIDEO=OFF
```

Comment: This might get better support on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ I see you have IPC setup on the listener though, are you trying to login from the same host?

Comment: Do you see the same thing with SQL\*Plus? Unless you have TWO_TASK set you aren't using TNS or the network layer with that connect string, so I'd think yasql is doing something odd. First things I'd do are check a different client, and check your environment for TWO_TASK. You might not be connecting to what you think.

Comment: Yes login from same host

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Can you add your ORACLE_SID and the contents of your tnsname.ora, or at least any entry which has an alias that matches your ORACLE_SID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably is not a problem of oracle,i see also ssh isn't working
probably bad routes/hops
I make some test now
Thanks for help

edit: Solution found,was a bad router